# Missing two-way data binding and computed property - Riot.js

Tags: riot.js

Even though I know I can add some events to update some of my variables using "event.target", how average could be updated when changing some of the scores, given the example below?

```
 <my-tag>
    <virtual each="{ criterias }">
        <label for="{ name }">{ name }:</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" max="10" value="{ score }" name="{ name }" id="{ name }">
    </virtual>
    <p>Average: { average }</p>

    <script>
        this.criterias = [
        {
            name: 'Plot',
            score: 8
        },
        {
            name: 'Audio',
            score: 9
        },
        {
            name: 'Graphics',
            score: 7
        }
        ]

        this.average = this.criterias.reduce((a, b) => a + b['score'], 0) / this.criterias.length
    </script>
</my-tag>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.update()` is called after any change event occurs like `onclick`, `oninput` etc. I believe your average can be calculated inside update function like so:

```
this.on('update', function(){
    this.average = this.criterias.reduce((a, b) => a + b['score'], 0);
});
```